# Smooth scroll inside overlay

Tags: javascript, css

I'm building a website that open an overlay when some `a` tags are clicked. Each link refers to one section inside the same overlay. I made this [pen](https://codepen.io/ddazal/pen/BOZxeP?editors=0010) as example but here is a summary:

1. The overlay is initially with a width of 0%
2. When the user clicks in a link, placed for example in the footer, the overlay change its width to 100%. Each `a` tag has the `id` of the section inside the overlay as its `href` value

   ```
   <!-- Overlay -->
   <div class="overlay">
     <div id="one">...</div>
     <div id="two">...</div>
     <div id="three">...</div>
   <div>
   <!-- Triggers -->
   <a href="#one">Section one</a>
   <a href="#two">Section two</a>
   <a href="#three">Section three</a>
   ```

I'm already changing the width of the overlay once a trigger is clicked. Now I need to make page jumps inside the overaly, I've been trying this way:

`section.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth' })`

Where section is the div inside the overlay. The problem I have is that although is scrolling, it's not matching the top of that div, it has a weird offset. Now the question: How do I fix that? I've been smashing my head against the wall but nothing comes out.

Thank you for your help

Comment: only css allowed or i can use jquery ?

Comment: Yes, you can use jQuery :)

Answer (score 0):

```js
function smoothyScroll(element,offset,speed) {
    
    if (!element) var element = ".scroll";
    if (!offset) var offset = 0;
    if (!speed) var speed = 500;
    
    $('a'+element+':not([href=#])').click(function() {
        
        $(element).removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
        
        offset = (!$(this).data('offset'))? offset : $(this).data('offset');
        speed = (!$(this).data('speed'))? speed : $(this).data('speed');
        
        if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
            var target = $(this.hash);
            target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
            if (target.length) {
                $('html,body').animate({
                    scrollTop: target.offset().top + offset
                }, speed);
                return false;
            }
        }
        
    }); // end click
    
    $('a'+element+'[href=#]').click(function() {
        $('html,body').animate({
            scrollTop: 0
        }, speed);
        return false;
    }); // end click
    
}

$(function() {
  smoothyScroll()
});
```

```css
* {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  color: #999;
}
h1 small {
  font-size: 0.5em;
  display: block;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: italic;
}
.scroll {
  color: #333;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.height1000 {
  height: 1000px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="overlay" class="height1000">
  <h1>smoothyScroll<small>simple jquery function for smooth scrolling between sections inside the same page</small></h1>
  <p>
    You don't need a jquery plugin to obtain a cool smooth scroll inside a web page and/or applications.
  </p>
  <a class="scroll" href="#target1">Smooth Scroll Link 1</a> 
  <a class="scroll" href="#target2">Smooth Scroll Link 2</a>
</div>

<div id="target1" class="height1000">
  <h2>Target Section 1</h2>
  <p>This is the first target section.</p>
  <p>
    <a href="#" class="scroll">BackTop</a>
  </p>
</div>

<div id="target2" class="height1000">
  <h2>Target Section 2</h2>
  <p>This is the first target section.</p>
  <p>
    <a href="#" class="scroll">BackTop</a>
  </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Move the

```
<button>Close</button>
```

out of the

```
<div class="overlay opened">
```

seems like it does some mess with the absolute position of the .overlay class